# Fill multiple combo boxes with multiple results

Tags: vb.net, datatable, combobox, bindingsource

I have five combo boxes that need to populate items related to the text inserted in each of them.

How can I reuse the same function to fill multiple combo boxes with different results in DataTable?

```vb
Private Sub Search()

    Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select stage from sample where stage like '%" + ComboBox1.Text + "%'", connection)

    Dim table As New DataTable
    adp.Fill(table)

    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "stage"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.PreviewKeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
            Search()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the DataSet instead to query multiple tables, then bind each table to the related combo box.

Comment: Sounds you have everything in a single table.

Comment: This is a lot of hits on the database. Do you already have a DataTable to fill these combos initially? You may be able to call the .Select method on the DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that works something like this:

```
Public Sub BindComboBox(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox, ByVal sSQL As String, ByVal sFieldNameOfReturnValue As String, ByVal sFieldNameOfDisplayText As String)
    Try
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, connection)
        Dim dtAllData As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(dtAllData)

        Dim xBindingContext As New BindingContext
        With cboBox
            .BindingContext = xBindingContext
            .DataSource = dtAllData

            .ValueMember = sFieldNameOfReturnValue.ToUpper
            .DisplayMember = sFieldNameOfDisplayText.ToUpper
        End With
    Catch Exp As Exception
        'Handle exceptions here
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then you would call this function like this:

```
Call BindComboBox(ComboBox1, "select stage from sample where stage like '%" + ComboBox1.Text + "%'", "stage", "stage")
Call BindComboBox(cboCompanies, "SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName, FROM Companies", "CompanyID", "CompanyName")
```

Comment: Vulerable to Sql injection.

Comment: Yep. But that was the SQL that Oswald Vinny submitted with their question. I would never do it like that. :)